# how to fix my website layout to small and big screens

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i have made a website by the help of Dreamweaver in HTML, CSS and JavaScript now my screen is 15.4 inch whenever i m opening in small screens so it give me an scroll bar to see whole of my website in the width form.

i have used PX with divs that i created my whole website instead of percentage but i don't know why i m facing this problem.

```
.wrapper
{
  width:1320px;
  height:760px;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:url(images/Background_Image.jpg) no-repeat;    
}
.wrapper .logo
{
    background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    width:395px;
    height:180px;
    margin-left:323px;
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
    // same method for other divs
}
```

Comment: You're using a fixed width, you might want to resort to using percentages instead. Or add multiple media queries to target smaller screens.

Comment: sorry how to handle smaller screens

Comment: i have read that using percentage is not good

Answer (score 1):

Add this meta tag to your head

viewport - most important and most useful of all the meta tags. width controls the width of viewport of device, initial-scale loads the initial zoom level when page loads

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Check [Mozilla Docs - Viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

make use of media queries

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

[Mozilla Docs - Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Percentage/em is good if you want your site to be responsive

Comment: Raunak Katthuria: thanks for u r reply i m new to HTML and CSS would u please tell me where to use this: @media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }

Comment: Add all the media queries in your css file, the main css which you would be using and if you are using inline then add it in <style></style> under <head>

Comment: sorry for stupid questions can i get all these queries from google or not

Comment: no it is specific to your design say i want some element to hide on small screen i will use @media screen and (max-width: 480px)  { .mySampleClass { display: none; } }, it is same as css but with some conditions

Comment: ohhhhhh i need all of my element over my webpage or i did not get u sorrrrrrry

Comment: you don't need all your element, you have to just specify those elements which you want or don't want for smaller screens.. Add the meta tag as of now and when you explore more about media queries then try adding them

Comment: elements that i wont need may be like can u give me some examples cos once again sorry and i need all of my elements

Comment: lets say you have one image that is 1200 * 800 of size width class name as desktop-image, and another image of size 200*150 with class name as handheld-image with display:none so in media queries you specify @media screen and (max-width: 480px) { .desktop-image {display: none; } .handheld-image { display: block; }  }

Comment: ohhhh now i got it do u know better than me that just in mobile we have different resolutions and also in computers so how many images should i use to handle this will not face my website heavy.